# Aspire VN-7-791-G fan control

Tags: dual-boot, acer, fan

I have Acer Aspire Nitro 17 (VN7-791-G). I installed Windows 10 and then Ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot).

My question is in Ubuntu while I'm doing most mundane tasks like surfing the web of writing some documents I hear my fan working and it gets loud. In Windows I only hear this kind of noises while playing a game.

Is there something I could do to improve this, install something or configure?

Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

after some research I found that adding acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor to kernel boot parameters makes a huge difference.

Daniel.

Comment: Hi Daniel, assuming you are the OT, please ask [Help Center > Contact](http://askubuntu.com/contact) to merge your accounts.